# How to reuse jquery selectors for performance in other jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, performance

I am not happy with my use of selectors and not sure how to reuse selectors in other selectors especially when the chain of selectors get long e.g.

```
    $("#documents div div:last-child #element");
```

I have written jquery code. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/skimread/vNMWX/16/)

Html:

```
    <button type="button" id="adddNewFile">Add</button>
    <br>
    <div id="documents"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#adddNewFile').click(function() {
    $("#documents").append("<div>");
    var d = $("#documents div:last-child");
    d.append('File '+$("#documents div").length+': <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>');

    d.append('<button type="button" id="removeFile">Remove</button>');
    d.append('<br/>');


    $("#documents div:last-child #removeFile").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();   
    });

   $('#documents').append(d);

});
```

How do I fix the above code to not have multiple jquery html element seeks like I am currently doing separately as in:

```
$('#documents')
$("#documents div:last-child
$("#documents div:last-child #removeFile")
```

this isn't optimal for performance. How do I correct it?

Comment: Just an FYI, if the element has an ID (which **must** be unique), just target that ID, no need to go down the ancestry line.

Comment: Change $("#documents div:last-child #removeFile") to $("#removeFile"). The other one is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache your selectors which would help in improving the performance.

Remove the nested click events and use event delegation to bind the events for dynamically created elements.

Use `.find`or a context when you are trying to use nested elements.

Use a Class instead of an `ID` for `removeFile` as that element instance may be inserted multiple times in the HTML. Use a class instead.

```
$(function () {
    // Cache your selectors
    var $documents = $("#documents"),
        $lastChild = $("div:last-child", $documents);
    $('#adddNewFile').click(function () {
        $documents.append("<div>");
        $lastChild.append('File ' 
                          + $("div", $documents).length 
                          + ': <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>');

        $lastChild.append('<button type="button" class="removeFile">Remove</button>');
        $lastChild.append('<br/>');
        $documents.append(d);
    });
    // Move the nested click event to the outside as it might bind the event
    // multiple times
    // Delegate the event as it is dynamically created element
    // Use a class instaed of ID as the latter has to be unique
    $documents.on('click', '.removeFile', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: +1, but just as an extra note `$(parent).find(child)` has been shown to be quicker than `$(child, parent)`

Comment: The click event doesn't get fired. Any idea why?

Comment: Simple issue the delete click event has to get binded to the delete button on the add file click event as it gets created dynamically. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/skimread/5uDDT/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var
$documents  = $('#documents'),
$lastChild  = $documents.find("div:last-child"),
$removeFile = $lastChild.find("#removeFile"); // also $removeFile = $("#removeFile");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign to variables and use `.find()`:

```
var $documents = $("#documents");
var $lastChild = $documents.find("div:last-child");
var $removeFile = $lastChild.find(".removeFile");
```

Note that I changed the last one to look for `class="removeFile"`. IDs have to be unique across the whole document, you can't repeat them in each DIV (you need to fix this in the `<input>` element as well -- it probably doesn't need an ID or class at all).

You can also avoid the need to rebind this every time you add a row, by using *delegation*:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#documents").on("click", ".removeFile", function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write it, the key is that you don't need to attach to the DOM to bind events to it, you can manipulate it before append to the DOM

```
$('#adddNewFile').click(function() {
    //create a new element in memory
    var d = $("<div />");
    var i = $("#documents div").length + 1;

    d.append('File '+i+': <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>');

    //create a button in memory
    var rmBtn = $("<button type=\"button\">Remove</button>");
    rmBtn.click(function() {
       $(this).parent().remove();   
    });
    d.append(rmBtn);
    d.append('<br/>');

    // Finally add to the DOM
    $("#documents").append(d);

});
```